# Cannot perform operation without a managed object context

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying add items from core data query to nsmutablearray but I'm getting this error:

```
"Cannot perform operation without a managed object context"
```

Here is my code:

```
NSPredicate *productPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext;
NSEntityDescription *description = [ NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest new];
request.predicate = productPredicate;
request.entity = description;
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


for (NSInteger i = 0; i < results.count; i++)
{

    NSString *productName = [[results objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"productName"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"productName == %@", productName];
    NSArray *match = [_listOfProducts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if (match == 0)
    {
        [self.listOfProducts addObject:[results objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Where I'm getting the error is at the momento of adding the object to nsmutablearray:

```
[self.listOfProducts addObject:[results objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error?, I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, do you have a managed object context?

Comment: @TomHarrington you mean the moc ? is there : NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext;

Comment: But is that non-nil? Having an `NSManagedObjectContext` variable doesn't mean the context exists.

Comment: is not nil,  po moc <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6000001e6500>

Comment: Why are you comparing match to 0 ? did you mean to say `if match.count==0`? As far as I know filteredArrayUsingPredicate won't return nil, if there are no matches, it returns an empty array.